# Why do I keep getting the 'Incorrect Syntax near 'Select'. Expecting Set' error?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm making a trigger for my database. In this case I'm running a book store, I have an author table and I have a books table. The author table contains the id,name,last name, birth date and death date of the author. My books table contains the book_id, id of its author, retail price, publish date and rating of the book. I'm trying to create a trigger that will double the price of any book with a rating below 6 upon the death of its author and if the rating is 6 it just raise the price by 50%. Basically if the death date column on the authors table is modified the retail price column on the books table should also be modified. This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER author_death
on authors
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(death)
    Begin 
    UPDATE books.retail_price
        SELECT CASE 
        when rating > 6 then retial_price * 2
        when rating = 6 then retail_price *1.5
    END
```

However my select is underlined in red and it gives me the "Incorrect Syntax near 'Select'. Expecting Set." error. How can I fix this?

Comment: look up `update` syntax in the documentation.

Comment: Ironically its a book, [the manual that is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually fairly far off on your syntax on all points.

First, you want to perform the update of `books` once *for each author* who has died, so you need to use a row trigger.

MySQL does not (according to the documentation) implement the `UPDATING` predicate. The way to test for this is to use the null-safe comparison operator, `<=>`, which returns **`false`** if one operand is **`null`** and **`true`** if both are **`null`**. (The regular `=` operator returns **`null`** if either operand is **`null`**.)

To access the columns in the record being updated, MySQL provides the **`OLD`** and **`NEW`** pseudorecords which contain the record as it *was* and as it *will be*, respectively. Comparing a column in **`OLD`** and **`NEW`** will tell you if that column has changed.

Presumably, you want to update the prices on all books by that author, and not on any other books. Therefore, you need to condition your `UPDATE` on the author ID, matching `books.author_id` with the author ID in either **`OLD`** or **`NEW`**. I chose **`NEW`** just because.

Finally, the easiest way to update to different values depending on rating is simply to perform two `UPDATE`s.

Her is my suggested code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER author_death
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON authors
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT (OLD.death <=> NEW.death)
  THEN
    UPDATE books
      SET retail_price = retail_price * 2
        WHERE rating < 6
          AND author_id = NEW.id;
    UPDATE books
      SET retail_price = retail_price * 1.5
        WHERE rating = 6
          AND author_id = NEW.id;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a MySQL `IF` statement requires the keywords `THEN` and `END IF`, those seem to be missing.

Was the intent to update the retail price of ALL books, or only the books by a particular author? I don't see a WHERE clause or any other conditional logic in the `UPDATE` statement.

I suspect you want your `UPDATE` statement to be of the form:

```
 UPDATE mytable 
    SET pricecolumn = expr 
  WHERE authorcol = somevalue
```

The expression `expr` returns the value you want to assign...

```
= mytable.myprice * CASE
                      WHEN mytable.myrating < 6 THEN 2.0 
                      WHEN mytable.myrating = 6 THEN 1.5
                      ELSE 1.0
                    END
```

You might want to test that expression in a SELECT statement, before you use it in a UPDATE

```
SELECT mytable.myrating
     , mytable.myprice  
     , mytable.myprice * CASE
                           WHEN mytable.myrating < 6 THEN 2.0 
                           WHEN mytable.myrating = 6 THEN 1.5
                           ELSE 1.0
                         END   AS new_price
 FROM mytable 
WHERE authorcol = somevalue
```

Comment: How can I insert this under a trigger? Also thanks for the help.